# Hiding non-cited references

Tags: bibitem

I am preparing a submission to arXiv. I had to put all my references as `\bibitem` within the main document in the body of `thebibliography`.

However, when I do so, also non-cited references appear in the document.

What can I do?

Comment: thebibliograhy list is just a normal list like `\begin{description}` or `\begin{itemize}` just use `\bibitem` for the ones you want and delete the rest. latex does no special sorting or filtering of that list.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose it is necessary to submit to arXiv so.

Comment: the normal way is to use bibtex and let bibtex generate the `thebibliography` list for you. then just replace `\bibligraphy{zzz}` by `\input{\jobname.bbl}` and arxiv is happy